# Unusual Oracle ALTER TABLE keyword, CHECK

Tags: sql, oracle

I was provided an unusual Oracle syntax recently:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName SHRINK SPACE CHECK;
```

What is odd about this syntax is the `CHECK` keyword.  Looking at the Oracle grammar for `ALTER TABLE` I cannot find any reference to what this keyword is implying and would love to have some reference documentation on this before I just make a change to our grammar that doesn't fit the official Oracle docs.

Comment: [This blog post](http://blog.itpub.net/19602/viewspace-2128657/) answers your question.  The `CHECK` at the end means that Oracle will check if shrink is possible, but it will not actually shrink the segment.

Answer (score 2):

The blog post mentioned is simply grabbing from MOS note 1132163.1

```
SQL> ALTER TABLE test SHRINK SPACE CHECK;
alter table test shrink space check
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-10636: ROW MOVEMENT is not enabled

-- the row movement is enabled in order to fix the error

SQL> ALTER TABLE test ENABLE ROW MOVEMENT;

Table altered.

-- running again the SHRINK SPACE CHECK against the table it says that the segment can be shrunk:

SQL> ALTER TABLE test SHRINK SPACE CHECK;
alter table test shrink space check
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-10655: Segment can be shrunk
```

but omits a very important point

"Note: In some cases the CHECK option can cause deadlocks"